# Python: How to search for repetitive strings within a string

Tags: python

If I had a string:

`x = 'ab123abc123123123123abcabcabc123123123123123123123abcabc'`

What would be the best approach to print the length of the longest sequence of '123' found in a row? For this string, I would want to get 7.

I have tried using regex, but I couldn't even find a way to return the substring with two or more occurrences. I have not used regex a lot and the best I came up with is:

`re.findall('123+', x)`

I also tried creating a way from scratch with loops, but that also failed.

I am stuck at this point and would really appreciate any help

Comment: Do you want to specifically find the length of the longest sequence of '123' or any substring which is part of the string?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing or tutorial saite, and we ask that you provide a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've tried based on your own research

Comment: Length of the longest sequence of '123'

Comment: Maybe if you could share with us what you've worked on so far, we could help. As @G.Anderson said, StackOverflow not a code-writing platform.

Comment: Using a regex is a reasonable approach so show us what you tried with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about it :

```
x = 'ab123abc123123123123abcabcabc123123123123123123123abcabc'
index = 0
count = 0
longest = 0
while index < len (x) :
    if x [index] == '1' :
        index += 1
        if x [index] == '2' :
            index += 1
            if x [index] == '3' :
                count += 1
                if count > longest :
                    longest = count
    else : count = 0
    index += 1
print (longest)
```